# Karaf+Pax CDI+custom Interceptors and Runtime annotations

Tags: osgi, cdi, apache-karaf, pax

I had tried to define and use custom runtime annotations in Karaf. It doesn't work for me.

I could configure my bundle to use Pax CDI+ OpenWebBeans CDI container.  Container works nice. I could see exposed services (standard annotation @OsgiServiceProvider ).

**But for defined custom interceptor marker with @AroundInvoke method doesn’t handle annotated with custom annotation methods.**

I use apache-karaf-3.0.2; pax.cdi 0.9.0; OpenWebBeans.

**Is this functionality already implemented for OSGi?
Any recommendations or samples for this?**

Thanks,
Gene

Answer (score 2):

Up to now, Pax CDI has not explicitly focused on interceptors, so there's a good chance of things not working as expected. On the other hand, there is a passing [`TransactionalTest`](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.cdi/blob/cdi-0.9.0/itest/src/it/itest-cdi10/src/test/java/org/ops4j/pax/cdi/test/TransactionalTest.java) which involves a custom interceptor from Apache DeltaSpike JPA.

Please have a look at that example to spot any obvious differences from your setup. If you still can't get your interceptor to work, please try to isolate the problem and submit a [JIRA issue](http://team.ops4j.org/browse/PAXCDI) with a test case.

Comment: Harald, we will look at this. Thank you for the direction.